# PHP call to undefined method, but method is defined... (not the same as other 2 similar questions)

Tags: php, caching, directory, fatal-error

I am going through a tutorial to build up a mock Flickr site in PHP. I am getting to the point where we are adding in all the user CRUD. The user class has already been defined and has methods that are being used and work. But once I added the methods for create, update, delete and save it says it can't find any of them... I have tried modifying the methods that do work, and they don't change. So to me it seems like there is a cached version of the user class, because changes in the user.php file aren't being recognized. I have used ctrl+F5 to refresh the cache, but that doesn't change anything...

This is my directory set up

```
wamp
  www
    photo_gallery
      includes
        config.php
        constants.php
        database.php
        database_object.php
        functions.php
        initialize.php
        session.php
        user.php
      public
        admin
          index,php
          login.php
          logout.php
          logfile.php
          test.php
        images
        javascript
        layouts
        stylesheets
        index.php
```

This is my initialize.php file that sets up the directory paths and loads all the files needed

```
<?php
    // Define the core paths
    // Define them as absolute paths to make sure that require_once works as expected

    //DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR is a php pre-defined constant
    // ( \ for Windows, / for Unix)
    defined('DS') ? null : define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

    // checks if lib path exists if not defines the site root with the directory specified below
    // ***** needs to be updated when switched directories, servers or computers
    defined('SITE_ROOT') ? null :
        define('SITE_ROOT', DS.'Users'.DS.'Alan D'.DS.'Desktop'.DS.'wamp'.DS.'www'.DS.'photo_gallery');

    // Checks if lib path has been defined, if not it defines it using site path above
    defined('LIB_PATH') ? null : define('LIB_PATH', SITE_ROOT.DS.'includes');

    // first load config
    require_once(LIB_PATH.DS.'config.php');

    // load basic functions that are available for all other files
    require_once(LIB_PATH.DS.'functions.php');

    // load core object classes for application
    require_once(LIB_PATH.DS.'session.php');
    require_once(LIB_PATH.DS.'database.php');
    require_once(LIB_PATH.DS.'database_object.php');

    // load database-related object classes
    require_once(LIB_PATH.DS.'user.php'); 


?>
```

This is the user class, it was simpler then this when I was testing, but I continued to follow through the steps to make the methods able to be dropped into my other classes when I create them.

```
<?php
    require_once('database.php');

    class User extends DatabaseObject{

        protected static $db_fields = array('id', 'user_name', 'password', 
        'first_name', 'last_name');
        protected static $table_name="users";

        public $id;
        public $user_name;
        public $password;
        public $first_name;
        public $last_name;

        public function full_name(){
            if(isset($this->first_name) && isset($this->last_name)){
                return $this->first_name . " " . $this->last_name;
            } else {
                return "";
            }       
        }

        // authenticates user by checking if there is a row with the 
        // input user name and password, then returns the object if found
        // if not it returns false
        public static function authenticate($user_name="", $password=""){
            global $database;
            $user_name = $database->escape_values($user_name);
            $password = $database->escape_values($password);

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM users ";
            $sql .= "WHERE user_name = '{$user_name}' ";
            $sql .= "AND password = '{$password}' ";
            $sql .= "LIMIT 1";
            $result_array = self::find_by_sql($sql);

            return !empty($result_array) ? array_shift($result_array) : false;
        }

        // checks to see if the given attribute exsits for the current object
        private function has_attribute($attribute){
            // associative array with all attributes key and value pairs
            $object_vars = $this->attributes();

            // just check if the key exists and return true or false
            return array_key_exists($attribute, $object_vars);          
        }

        // returns a key value hash of the objects variables and values
        protected function attributes(){
            // get_object_vars returns an associative array with all attributes
            // (incl private) as the keys and their current values as value
            // return get_object_vars($this);   

            // this goes through the db fields and populates the hash
            $attributes = array();
            foreach(self::$db_fields as $field){
                if(property_exists($this, $field)){
                    $attributes[$field] = $this->$field;
                }
            }
            return $attributes;
        }

        // returns a sanitized (sql escaped) array of all the attributes
        protected function sanitized_attributes(){
            global $database;
            $clean_attributes = array();

            // sanitize the values before submitting
            // Note: does not alter the actual value of each attribute
            foreach($this->attributes() as $key => $value){
                $clean_attributes[$key] = $database->escape_value($value);
            }
            return $clean_attributes;
        }

        // this function check to see if the record is already there
        // and determines whether to create or update.
        public function save(){
            return isset($this->id) ? $this->update() : $this->create();
        }

        public function create(){
            global $database;
            $attributes = $this->sanitized_attributes();

            $sql = "INSERT INTO ".self::$table_name." (";
            $sql .= join(", ", array_keys($attributes));
            $sql .= ") VALUES ('";
            $sql .= join("', '", array_values($attributes));
            $sql .= "')";
            if($database->query($sql)){
                $this->id = $database->insert_id();
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public function update(){
            global $database;
            $attributes = $this->sanitized_attributes();

            // set up the key, value string needed for the update statement
            foreach ($attributes as $key => $value){
                $attribute_pairs[] = "{$key}='{$value}'";
            }

            $sql = "UPDATE ".self::$table_name." SET ";
            $sql .= join(", ", $attribute_pairs);
            $sql .= " WHERE id='". $database->escape_value($this->id);

            $database->query($sql);
            return($database->affected_rows() == 1) ? true : false;
        }

        public function delete(){
            global $database;

            $sql = "DELETE FROM ".self::$table_name." ";
            $sql .= "WHERE id=". $database->escape_value($this->id);
            $sql .= " LIMIT 1";

            $database->query($sql);
            return($database->affected_rows() == 1) ? true : false;
        }       
    }
?>
```

In the admin/test.php file it is set up like this

```
<?php
require_once('../../includes/initialize.php');

if (!$session->is_logged_in()) { redirect_to("login.php"); }
?>

<?php  include_layout_template('admin_header.php'); ?>

<?php
$user = new User();

$user->user_name = "jDoe";
$user->password = "pass";
$user->first_name = "Jamie";
$user->last_name = "Doe";
echo $user->full_name();
$user->save();

//$user = User::find_by_id(1);
//$user->password = "pass1";
//$user->update();

?>

<?php  include_layout_template('admin_footer.php'); ?>
```

When I run that page I get the admin header layout to load, the full name is printed on the screen and directly below it says:

Fatal error: Call to undefined method User::save() in C:\wamp\www\photo_gallery\public\admin\test.php on line 17

The same was happening with create and update... but these functions do exist in the user.php file, I even emptied everything out of the methods to makes sure there was no bug in the php code inside of them.

Then I tried the test from the public folder, through public/index.php

```
<?php
require_once('../includes/initialize.php');

if (!$session->is_logged_in()) { redirect_to("login.php"); }
?>

<?php  include_layout_template('admin_header.php'); ?>

<?php
$user = new User();

$user->user_name = "jDoe";
$user->password = "pass";
$user->first_name = "Jamie";
$user->last_name = "Doe";
$user->full_name();
$user->create();


?>

<?php  include_layout_template('admin_footer.php'); ?>
```

But this doesn't even load the admin header layout... and just gives me the same error as the other test file did. I am pretty positive that I am navigating to the correct path based on the directory set up.

For the life of me I cannot understand why/how the user object isn't being updated when I add things to the user class inside user.php. Or how I could use other methods I had previously defined in user, but they don't change when I modify them... Does php do any caching of objects that I am unaware of? I even pulled the user.php out of the includes directory... and everything still runs as explained above...

Any insight would be greatly appreciated. I have been searching around for a while now trying to find someone with a similar issue but I can't find one. Thanks for reading.

Comment: You should probably show your `User` class.

Comment: I just added it, I didn't post before because I think it has something to do with the directory set up or caching. Since I deleted the user.php file from the includes directory and everything above still worked the same...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems in your initialize.php you have an additional directory in the `SITE_ROOT` definition compared to what you show in your directory structure.  Do you still have another copy of this code perhaps in `photo_gallery` directory that this is actually including files from?

This is where all your includes are pointing to:

```
/Users/Alan D/Desktop/wamp/www/photo_gallery/includes
```

Comment: On second thought you are right :X I guess I have a copy of the project on my desktop as well as C:\wamp\www\photo_gallery\public I'm not really sure how that happened... I had to reinstall wamp a couple times because apache wouldn't start I guess when I switched the working directory I forgot to edit that file... like I have commented that I need to do... thanks for looking over this, stupid mistake on my part.

Comment: For the record, if you are dealing with a codebase that will be moving around within directory structures, you should probably use the PHP magic constants `__FILE__`, `__DIR__`, etc. to automatically set the site_root for you, with all links relative to the initiation file's directory location.

Comment: Very valid point, I was mostly just following the tutorial. Then once I got to the end I was going to fix a bunch of things, making the path dynamic will definitely be one of them now. Thanks again.